# Change color of the iPhone screen

Tags: iphone, colors, touch, multi-touch

I need to change the color of the iPhone screen when i touch on it. The only thing i need to do is to change the color of the area where i am touching. if i am placing a star on the screen as touch then only that area color will be changed.

Any idea about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at some of the [Graphics and Animation iPhone SDK Samples](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/navigation/index.html?section=Resource+Types&topic=Sample+C#section=Topics&topic=Graphics%20%26amp%3B%20Animation) - there are samples there that show how to paint with different colours and other samples of how to use user input.